# Springboot 2.5.x and above with mariadb driver gives java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=11812758) Connection is closed

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy Spring cloud data flow using helm on a kubernetes cluster. Below are the parameters I am passing.

```
helm3 --kube-context my-cluster install my-release bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow --namespace my-namespace --set server.service.type=NodePort --set server.image.tag=2.9.2-debian-10-r0 --set rabbitmq.enabled=false --set kafka.enabled=false --set skipper.enabled=false --set mariadb.enabled=false --set 'externalDatabase.dataflow.url=jdbc:mysql://****.****.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dataflow?useSSL=false' --set usePipelineAuth=false --set useBatchMultiSend=false --set allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true --set externalDatabase.dataflow.username=username --set externalDatabase.password=pwd --set externalDatabase.driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --set server.configuration.batchEnabled=true --set server.configuration.streamingEnabled=false --set server.livenessProbe.enabled=false --set server.readinessProbe.enabled=false --set externalDatabase.hibernateDialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect --set server.resources.limits.memory=16Gi --set server.resources.limits.cpu=15 --set server.resources.requests.memory=2Gi --set server.resources.requests.cpu=1000m --set server.ingress.enabled=true --set server.ingress.hostname=lab-development-dataflow-v2.dev.miqdigital.com --set server.ingress.ingressClassName= --set server.ingress.apiVersion=networking.k8s.io/v1 --set server.composedTaskRunner.image.tag=2.9.2-debian-10-r0 --set deployer.environmentVariables=SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=integration --set deployer.resources.limits.cpu=2 --set deployer.resources.limits.memory=6Gi --set deployer.resources.requests.cpu=0.5 --set deployer.resources.requests.memory=2Gi --set deployer.podSecurityContext.runAsUser=0
```

There are few applications which are registered in SCDF. Applications with Spring boot version 2.1.x runs successfully and the applications above 2.5.x gives database connectivity error .

Error log:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[ERROR] 2022-09-20 07:41:08 [main      ] [/] [] SpringApplication:865 - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
    at com.miq.dsp.batch.DspBatchApplication.main(DspBatchApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=****My_DB_URL****)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=11812758) could not load system variables
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1394)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=11812758) could not load system variables
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:188)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.requestSessionDataWithShow(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1114)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.readPipelineAdditionalData(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1075)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.postConnectionQueries(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:885)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:600)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1389)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=11812758) Connection is closed
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.cmdPrologue(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1946)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:249)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.requestSessionDataWithShow(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1089)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw a log here

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

1. Please check your connection. I think spring boot cannot connect to your MySQL server
2. Try to use the MySQL driver version that supports your Mysql Server version

Comment: I tried to pass the mysql driver --set externalDatabase.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as I am using mysql connection properties, but with that I am not able to deploy this